# I need checkboxes in combine to act as an AND, not as an OR

Tags: css, checkbox

I used to be a programmer but did not program for 15 years so I am pre-web. I spent the last 2 days learning HTML and CSS to put together this: https://www.visualdiaryguide.com/selector.html

The problem is when I check the boxes, I need the selections to reflect the combination of Art Forms and Styles, not a collection. For example, when I click 2D-Painting and Realism, white selections should be reduced not expanded.

It feels like I'd need to re-design this whole thing (which I am hoping is not the case). I don't really want to also learn JavaScript :(

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I am assuming you can see the HTML and CSS code from the website so I am not including them here.

I tried to combine IDs, etc but to no avail.

I am assuming you can see the HTML and CSS code from the website so I am not including them here.
https://www.visualdiaryguide.com/selector.html

Comment: Please include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of giving your entire website as reference

Comment: If i understand you need javascript/jquery to accomplish your goal.

Comment: I prepared a fragment of the code but it is still too large to fit into this comment box (even when split into CSS and HTML). I'll try to upload the fragment elsewhere and provide a pointer.

Comment: I guess the gist of it is this: 
#af2DPainting:checked ~ .characters [data-teams~="af2DPainting"] h2,
#af2DPrintmaking:checked ~ .characters [data-teams~="af2DPrintmaking"] h2,
#afRealism:checked ~ .characters [data-teams~="afRealism"] h2,
#afDadaism:checked ~ .characters [data-teams~="afDadaism"] h2,

Comment: And this: <ul class="characters">
<li id="ch-1-5" data-teams="af2DPainting af2DPrintmaking af2DDrawing af2DPhotoanddigitalmedia af2DGraphics af2DTextiles af2DCollage af3DCeramics af3DSculpture af3DInstallation af3DTextiles af3DJewellery af4DPerformanceArt af4DTimebasedvideo af4DDigitalAnimation afRealism afDadaism afSurrealism afFuturism afContemporaryAustralianart afInternationalart afImpressionism afExpressionism afPostmodernism afAboriginalTorresStraitIslanderArt afAsianart afAncientart afPopArt afUrbanArt afCraftspeople afPhotographers afOpArt"><h2>1.5 What are you into?</h2></li></ul>

Comment: In HTML, data-teams tag contains all possible values to match for h2 tag and in CSS, all checkbox selectors search for any of these values.

I was thinking when a checkbox is checked and some h2 tags are selected with white color, is it possible then to select only the white colors for the next checkbox? And so on and so forth... Keep narrowing the selection base on the new color.

Comment: Also, I am sorry for the mess. I use Weebly and there is all that code around my code in the web site. I hope the fragments help. You can also search for "body {" in the code, it takes you to my code.

Comment: I guess I could simply this question down to this:

In CSS, is it possible to select based on current color? In the above, when I check a box, it searches its tag in all the activity lines and paints them white. If it is possible to narrow the next search to only while lines, then it would work for me.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this as an answer as I believe the below will conclude this trail and help others trying to achieve the same thing. Sfilli_81 above was correct. This required a little JavaScript magic, in fact, a little jQuery and some design changes. Checkboxes became 2 sets of radio buttons. You can see the live version by clicking the link in the original question.

var aForm = 0;
var aStyle = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("[name='ArtForm']").click(function() {

        aForm = $(this);

        // Restore default color
        $(".characters [related^='a'] hh2").css("color", "#204A0B");

        // Color in the selected Form and Style combination
        if (aForm.is(':checked')) {
           if (aStyle === 0) {
               $(".characters [related~='" + aForm.prop('id') + "'] hh2").css("color", "white");
           } else {
               $(".characters [related~='" + aForm.prop('id') + "'][related~='" + aStyle.prop('id') + "'] hh2").css("color", "white");
           }
        }

    });


    $("[name='ArtStyle']").click(function() {

        aStyle = $(this);

        // Restore default color
        $(".characters [related^='a'] hh2").css("color", "#204A0B");

        // Color in the selected Form and Style combination
        if (aStyle.is(':checked')) {
           if (aForm === 0) {
               $("[.characters related~='" + aStyle.prop('id') + "'] hh2").css("color", "white");
           } else {
               $(".characters [related~='" + aForm.prop('id') + "'][related~='" + aStyle.prop('id') + "'] hh2").css("color", "white");
           }
        }

    });

});

Comment: Oh, I was hoping posting as an answer would protect the indentation. It doesn't look very appetizing. Sorry!